# How to search in datasets for specific IDs and report values from the neighboring cell into new column(s)

Tags: r, formatting, data-wrangling

I've a dataset similar to this (clearly much bigger):

```
    ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    MASS <- c(324,162,508,675,670,832)
    DIFF <- c("2","1","5","0","3&6","5")
    d <- data.frame(ID, MASS, DIFF)

  ID MASS DIFF
1  1  324    2
2  2  162    1
3  3  508    5
4  4  675    0
5  5  670  3&6
6  6  832    5
```

Is there any way in R to set up up a script that would:

- read the values reported in the column DIFF (not considering & or 0)
- find the same values in the column ID
- paste the corresponding values present in the next cell (belonging to the column MASS), into a new column (one value per cells) next to the column DIFF that reports the IDs- if more than one values are reported in the column DIFF, make new columns (MASS1, MASS2, MASS3...)

The aim would be to obtain something like what is reported here below, I hope this can clarify my clumsy description of the problem:

```
  ID MASS DIFF MASS1 MASS2
1  1  324    2   162    NA
2  2  162    1   324    NA
3  3  508    5   670    NA
4  4  675    0    NA    NA
5  5  670  3&6   508   832
6  6  832    5   670    NA
```

Many thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels pretty hacky and overly complicated, but it works. Maybe someone else has a more efficient method:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

d |> 
  separate_rows(DIFF, convert = TRUE) |> 
  left_join(d, c("DIFF" = "ID")) |>
  select(-DIFF.y) |> 
  group_by(ID) |> 
  mutate(DIFF = paste(DIFF, collapse = "&")) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  rename(MASS = MASS.x) |> 
  group_split(ID) |> 
  map(~ .x |>
        mutate(temp = row_number()) |> 
        pivot_wider(values_from = MASS.y, names_from = temp, names_glue = "MASS{temp}")) |> 
  bind_rows()

# A tibble: 6 × 5
     ID  MASS DIFF  MASS1 MASS2
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   324 2       162    NA
2     2   162 1       324    NA
3     3   508 5       670    NA
4     4   675 0        NA    NA
5     5   670 3&6     508   832
6     6   832 5       670    NA
```

Comment: Many thanks for your kind reply and effort, although I'm a total newbie of R I knew this could be tricky script to set up so, again, thanks for sharing your solution. I tried to run it but I always get errors that I can't figure out why, basically for each line of the script i get message regarding the > symbol ( e.g. Error: unexpected '>' in "d |  >" ).

Comment: You may be using an old version of R. I'm using v4.2. You can either update R to the latest version, or change `|>` to `%>%` throughout.

Comment: That was indeed the case, just an old version. Again, many thanks for your help and troubleshooting!